# Form closed after run a function

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

at first sorry for bad English!
I have a program in Vb.Net and i use a module for check the license like this :

```
Public Sub main()
    Dim th As Thread = New Thread(AddressOf f1show)
    Try
        Dim cn As New SqlConnection("something")
        Dim query As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Test WHERE id = 1")
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader
        Dim dbtext As String = ""
        query.Connection = cn
        Try
            cn.Open()
            dr = query.ExecuteReader()
        Catch
            MsgBox("notOk")
            Form3.ShowDialog()
        End Try
        If dr.HasRows Then
            Do While dr.Read()
                dbtext = dr("TEXT1")
            Loop
        Else
            Form3.ShowDialog()
        End If
        cn.Close()
        If dbtext <> "" Then
            Dim dbwords As String() = zn.Custom_Decrypt(dbtex)
            Dim dbword As String = dbwords(0)
            If ZN.Custom_Decrypt(dbword) = "a" Then
                Form1.ShowDialog()
                'this where main form show and license is Ok
            Else
                Form3.ShowDialog()
            End If
        End If
    Catch
        Form3.ShowDialog()
    End Try
End Sub
```

in above code form1 is main form and form3 is license form and Zn is my module
its work correctly and show form1 when license exists in database
but in form1 when for a button i use a function (any function) application exit without any reason but when i change startup to form1 functions are ok and work correctly
what i should do ? somebody advise me to change the startup but problem doesn't solved

Comment: Check that your Shutdown mode isn't set to "When startup form closes", because it looks like you're showing your main form as a dialog, which means it will cause the whole application to exit once the main form dialog is closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tnx to all i solved this problem
its need to use application.run code
i change the Form3.ShowDialog() to application.run(new form3())

```
Form3.ShowDialog() ===>> application.run(new form3())
```